# How to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse with a URL having a dot in it?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd, httpd.conf

I am using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. In just simple cases its wouks great but as I have a URL ending with a ".jpg" it just misses it. For example :-

Consider the statement below :-

The request URL that I want to pass is  `https://xxxxxx/photos/2222.jpg` . I write the statements mentioned below in httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /photos/ http://10.40.4.170:80/PrimeCoreServices/api/users/photos/
ProxyPassReverse /photos/ http://10.40.4.170:80/PrimeCoreServices/api/users/photos/
```

Now on the other side on my sever I recieve request only like `/photos/2222` the `.jpg` part is fully omitted, without which I cant do anything. Please help me to fix this. The apache web server is not allowing me to parse this `.jpg` with the URL.

I actually want to know how to write the configuration for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your ProxyPass statements are both correct. The problem is not here.

Your URL will resolve to the following request:
`https://xxxxxx/photos/2222.jpg --> http://10.40.4.170:80/PrimeCoreServices/api/users/photos/2222.jpg`

You may have a Rewrite breaking things, or may be handling parameters wrong on your backend server.